# How to add a link to an external stylesheet in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, css

I would like to add Font Awesome External StyleSheet () to SharePoint Online so that I can use the icons on my Quick Launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the master page file, add the following line just before closing the `<head>` tag.

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration" Name="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Comment: Where do I locate `http://<siteCollectionURL>/_catalogs/masterpage/customer_name/css/`  in SharePoint Designer? If there is a specific link where they show, I appreciate.

Comment: find the `<\head>` in your masterpage

Comment: If your editing the HTML-file of the masterpage, add the <!--SPM: thingy both before and after.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the `http` bit in the Name part?

Comment: True, you should use http as well. Like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922833/fontawesome-icons-not-showing-why Editing.

Comment: Thanks Benny,it actually worked AND for some reason I had to add **https** so that it wouldn't be blocked.